# ¿Cómo solucionar el error >> ORA-01861: el literal no coincide con la cadena de formato , al actualizar en Jpa Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

Tengo dos servicios, uno que inserta y otro que actualiza sobre la tabla Dia, para el insert utilizo el TO_DATE dentro de mi query y lo hace sin problema,si inserta bien,  pero al momento de probar el query del Update, me manda el siguiente error

> SQL Error: 1861, SQLState: 22008
>
> ORA-01861: el literal no coincide con la cadena de formato

el formato de fecha que mando es:  **2023-07-27** que es el mismo que mando cuando quiero insertar,pero en el Update no lo acepta y por eso en mi query del update agregue tambien el TO_DATE, pero no se si este mal mi query o porque no lo acepta, les comparto mis servicios y sus respectivos querys

Controller

```
    @PostMapping("/altaDia")
    private void agregarDiaDescanso(@RequestBody DiaEntity diaInhabil) throws Exception {

        try {
            diaService.agregarDia(diaInhabil);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in  Values ");
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @PutMapping("/actualizarDia")
    public void actualizarDiaDescanso(@RequestBody DiaEntity entidad) throws Exception {
        
        try {
            diaService.actualizarDia(entidad);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in  Values ");
            throw e;
        }

    }
```

Service Impl

```
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void agregarDia(DiaEntity diaInhabil) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("DATE SERVICE      " + diaInhabil.getFechaDescanso());

        try {
            diaRepository.guardarNuevoDiaDescanso(diaInhabil.getFechaDescanso(), diaInhabil.getDescripcionDia(),
                    diaInhabil.getDescansoMex(), diaInhabil.getDescansoUs());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("An error ocurred to insert  Data");

        }

    }
    
    
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void actualizarDia(DiaEntity entidad) throws Exception {
        try {
            CatDiaInhabilEntity bd = catDiaInhabilRepository.findQueryById(entidad.getFechaDescanso());

            if (entidad.getDescripcionDia() == null) {
                entidad.setDescripcionDial(bd.getDescripcionDia());
            }
            if (entidad.getDescansoMex() == null) {
                entidad.setDescansoMex(bd.getDescansoMex());
            }
            if (entidad.getDescansoUs() == null) {
                entidad.setDescansoUs(bd.getDescansoUs());
            }

            diaRepository.actualizarDiaDescanso(entidad.getDescripcionDia(),
                    entidad.getDescansoMex(), entidad.getDescansoUs(), entidad.getFechaDescanso());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("An error ocurred ");

        }

    }
```

Repository

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO DIA (FECHA_DESCANSO, DESCRIPCION_DIA, DESCANSO_MEX, DESCANSO_US) values (TO_DATE(?1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), ?2, ?3, ?4) ", nativeQuery = true)
void guardarNuevoDiaDescanso(String fechaDescanso, String descripcionDia, String descansoMex, String descansoUs);


@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE DIA D SET D.DESCRIPCION_DIA=?1, D.DESCANSO_MEX=?2, D.DESCANSO_US=?3 WHERE TO_DATE('D.FECHA_DESCANSO=?4', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')", nativeQuery = true)
void actualizarDiaDescanso(String descripcionDia, String descansoMex, String descansoUs, String fechaDescanso);
```

esta mal mi query? o como debo de enviar la fecha para que me actualice correctamente?

Comment: Aparte, ese `TO_DATE` del `UPDATE`, mmmmm... ¿Tenés la certeza de que está bien escrito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La cláusula `where` de la sentencia es incorrecta.

Voy a sacarla primero de la cadena y a dividirla en líneas, para que se vea más claro:

```sql
UPDATE DIA D 
   SET   D.DESCRIPCION_DIA=?1
       , D.DESCANSO_MEX=?2
       , D.DESCANSO_US=?3 
 WHERE TO_DATE('D.FECHA_DESCANSO=?4', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

`to_date` es una función que solamente convierte una cadena a fecha y lo que devuelve es un `datetime`. Supongo que lo que quieres es comparar la fecha almacenada con la ingresada, por lo que sería:

```sql
UPDATE DIA D 
   SET   D.DESCRIPCION_DIA=?1
       , D.DESCANSO_MEX=?2
       , D.DESCANSO_US=?3 
 WHERE D.FECHA_DESCANSO=TO_DATE(?4, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

- He sacado el nombre del campo y el operador de comparación de igualdad de la función
- No hace falta encerrar el parámetro entre comillas `''`, por lo que las he quitado

Volviendo todo al código de java, quedaría:

```java
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE DIA D SET D.DESCRIPCION_DIA=?1, D.DESCANSO_MEX=?2, D.DESCANSO_US=?3 WHERE D.FECHA_DESCANSO=TO_DATE(?4, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')", nativeQuery = true)
void actualizarDiaDescanso(String descripcionDia, String descansoMex, String descansoUs, String fechaDescanso);
```

Comment: si me funcionó, muchas gracias :)